# How to translate hexadecimal code to binary code?

Tags: python, utf-8, binary, hex

I have been reading a lot of sources but I'm still confused on how to calculate it.
I'm doing an exercise which asks:

> which of the following bit sequences (presented as hexadecimal numbers) represent valid UFT-8 string and in the case they are valid UTF-8 strings, how many code does the bit sequence correspond to?
>
> ```
> 0x30c0
> 0x303C
> 0xE0ADAA
> 0x3AA
> ```

Comment: What is confusing you? Converting hexadecimal to binary or how UTF-8 works?

Comment: I'm confused on how to translate such as 0x303c

Comment: C is translated to 1100 then 3 is 11 then 0 is 0 then x is 1011 so why the answer is 11000000111100 Joni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one definition: [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encode an Unicode code-point to a sequence of 1 to 6 bytes.

0x30C0 use hexadecimal notation to represent 2 bytes. Assuming the high order byte appearing first in the byte sequence, this is equivalent to 0x30 followed by 0xC0. You can write that in Python 3:

```
>>> seq = b"\x30\xC0"
>>> seq
b'0\xc0'
```

Assuming this *could be* an UTF-8 encoded stream of bytes, we could try the `decode` method:

```
>>> seq.decode("UTF-8")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

??? Doesn't work. The sequence is not proper UTF-8.

---

Lets do the same for the next sequence:

```
>>> seq = b"\x30\x3C"
>>> seq.decode("UTF-8")
'0<'
```

Ah, ah! No exception. This is proper UTF-8 corresponding to the string of 2 code points `0<`.

---

The third is interesting:

```
>>> seq = b"\xE0\xAD\xAA"
>>> seq.decode("UTF-8")
'୪'
>>> len(seq.decode("UTF-8"))
1
```

Those 3 bytes are used to encode only one code point.
But which character ... hum ... "code point" is this? Python has the `ord` function to know that:

```
>>> ord(seq.decode("UTF-8"))
2922
```

Code point 2922 (décimal). That is in hexadecimal...

```
>>> "{:04X}".format( ord(seq.decode("UTF-8")) )
'0B6A'
```

So the sequence of bytes `0xE0 0xAD 0xAA` encode as UTF-8 the unicode code point `U+0B6A`. But which character is that? Python embed a module to query the Unicode database:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name( seq.decode("UTF-8") )
'ORIYA DIGIT FOUR'
```

So it is: This is the code point corresponding to [digit 4 in Oriya writing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriya_alphabet#Numerals).

Comment: @ErikaSawajiri I have expanded my answer to show you how to extract the code point of an unicode character and how to query the Unicode database to have the official name corresponding to a character.

Comment: Sylvain thank you so much!! ~

Answer (score 1):

The question is very badly posed. Those are all numbers, not strings. I suspect that meant to represent byte sequences, in which case they should have written it as:

```
0x30 0xc0
0x30 0x3C
0xE0 0xAD 0xAA
0x03 0xAA
```

...or something like that.

If that's in fact what the question means (unclear), then it can be seen by trivial inspection which ones are invalid UTF-8:

- The first one is invalid. The byte `0xc0` is never ever valid UTF-8.
- The second one contains only ASCII, so by definition it is valid UTF-8 also.
- The third one has at first glance the correct form (first byte greater than 0xc1, second and third between 0x80 and 0xbf). You can decode it with pen and paper by following the definition of UTF-8 and see that it is valid.
- The fourth one is not valid: it has a continuation byte `0xaa` without a valid first byte of a multibyte sequence.

**OR**, you can just try to let the computer decode them, and it will give you an error for the ones that are invalid. For example, using Python version 3,

```
>>> bytes([0x30,0xc0]).decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 1: invalid start byte
>>> bytes([0x30,0x3c]).decode('utf-8')
'0<'
>>> bytes([0xe0,0xad,0xaa]).decode('utf-8')
'୪'
>>> bytes([0x03,0xaa]).decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 1: invalid start byte
>>>
```